# DRD4 genes and their connections to Dopamine 2 subtype

Tags: genetics

I am trying to find out how the DRD4 gene correlates with the dopamine 2 family subtype receptor in the brain. Does a certain amount of methylation of DRD4 affect how much Dopamine is present in the brain?